# Given an element, how to detect which "n" it is in an "nth of type"?

Tags: javascript, browser, selectors-api

I know how to select the nth element of a certain type `document.querySelectorAll('.myClass')[n]`,

but **given** an element `myEl = document.querySelector('.myClass .myOtherClass')`,

**how do I then determine its place** (its "n") in the array of elements selected by `document.querySelectorAll('.myClass')`?

Comment: Just use `indexOf`?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.myClass').indexOf(document.querySelector('.myClass .myOtherClass'))`

Comment: Or are you specifically asking about [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)?

Answer (score 1):

do this:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".myClass").indexOf(yourElement) // ==> your index
```

Answer (score 1):

U can try something like that:

```
Array.prototype.indexOf.call(document.querySelectorAll('.myclass'),myEl)
```